# Read mobile SMS through ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to ionic. I was trying to create an application that could read our handset(mobile) SMS's.

Is there any way to do the same through ionic ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this Cordova Plugin to do the magic:
https://github.com/dimitrismistriotis/ReadSmsCordovaPlugin